# Python doesn't uptade table

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am trying to do database GUI app with Python but i can't update table. There is no error but i run program after i look Mysql workbench nothing changes.

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',                                                   database='databese', user='user',                                              
         password='password')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.conn.commit()

    def update(self, isim):
        self.conn.commit()
        self.cur.execute("UPDATE hakemler SET durum='UYGUNSUZ' WHERE isim='%s' ",isim)

    def updateback(self, isim):
        self.cur.execute("UPDATE hakemler SET durum='UYGUN' WHERE isim='%s'",isim)
        self.conn.commit()
db = DB()

def çıkar():
    db.update(id.get())
def gerial():
    db.updateback(hakem1.get())
hakem = StringVar()
hakem1= StringVar()
id  = IntVar()
entry1 = tk.Entry(mazeretli, width=20, textvariable=id)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)
button1 = tk.Button(mazeretli, text="Kişiyi Listeden Çıkar", command=çıkar)
button1.grid(row=2, column=2)
entry2 = tk.Entry(mazeretli, width=20, textvariable=hakem1)
entry2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button2 = tk.Button(mazeretli, text="Kişiyi Geri Al", command=gerial)
button2.grid(row=4, column=2)
```

There is no error masseges or something . Code just don't work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
def update(self, isim):
    self.conn.commit()
    self.cur.execute("UPDATE hakemler SET durum='UYGUNSUZ' WHERE isim='%s' ",isim)
```

Database actions require that you `commit` after the action, in order for the changes to be written to the database. You've got the order reversed. Replace the order:

```
def update(self, isim):
    self.cur.execute("UPDATE hakemler SET durum='UYGUNSUZ' WHERE isim='%s' ",isim)
    self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: Well , i tried this and in the example, function updateback it is like what you say